# Electric field generated by an infinite plane paradoxon

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

Every element of the distribution generates weaker electric field at a larger distancce. Although other arguments involving gauss' law or taking the limit of the field result it's constancy. How could the electric field at the two positions be equal?
[image: the problem]

Comment: You should either move this question to Physics stack exchange, or give more details about the mathematics involved in electromagnetism.

Comment: What is a "paradoxon"?

Comment: The above mentioned sums are actually equal. According to this they're not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be a rough explanation.  From your figure, the size of the electric field $\delta E(\ell)$ corresponding to the same infinitesimal area $\delta a$ decreases as the vertical distance $\ell$ goes up.  However, the angle $\theta(\ell)$ each field line makes with the vertical line decreases with the distance $\ell$.  Hence, the vertical component $\cos\big(\theta(\ell)\big)\delta E(\ell)$ of the electric field is not necessarily a decreasing function of $\ell$ (noting that $\cos(t)$ increases as $t$ decreases, for $t\in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$).  You can make a careful calculation to verify that this is the case.

Comment: At evaluating the electric field the factor corresponding to θ was involved. Yet still, the fields by δE(ℓ) differed.

Comment: So?  If the cosine term is small, it can bring down the contribution from that area.  $10^{10000}\cdot 0$ is still $0$.

Comment: [here[(http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/imgel2/eled.png) It explicitly gives you the field with all the cosines prevously involved in the integration. Its easy to see that if z is not identical in the configurations the field by the regions neither.

Comment: Sure, if you have a finite charged plane, then the vertical distance matters (and the electric field strength indeed decreases as the vertical distance increases).  But you are talking about an infinite charged plane, aren't you?  In that case, you have to take limit $R\to\infty$ in your link.  See what happens?

Comment: Thats why this question was titled a paradoxon. It should be independent of the distance, yet by intuition if all of the members of your first sum is larger then the entire sum supposed to be larger as well.

Comment: It's still not a paradox, if you think carefully.  You ignored angular contributions, and then jumped at the wrong conclusion.

Comment: How did I ignored it? They were the part of the calculating process which lead to the formula I shared. Then I referred to that. Could you explain what am I missing here?

Comment: In the original question, you ignored the angular contributions.  In the link you shared, there is nothing wrong with it, but the link does not describe the same problem that you seem to ask here on stackexchange.  I already explained why, but you simply neglected to read my explanation about that.

Comment: My questions is this: How can the electric fields at the two different positions be same, if the field contributed by the same regions are not equal?

Comment: Two people have tried to give you an explanation.  In addition, the link you gave me also provides an answer to your question.  Take a look at it, carefully.

Comment: Both anwsers havent anwsered my question. How can two series converge to the same value if the first series' every element is larger than the others'.

Comment: We explained that this claim "every element is larger than the others" is false, yet you keep on believing that this claim is true.  I am not sure how we can help you, if you hold this strange religious belief very strongly.

Comment: You can check yourself for distances z and n*z (n>1, just plug into the formula) that the field produced by the  same regions will always be larger for shorter distances.

Comment: Why did you give me the link when you refuse to look at it and think hard about it?  What you claimed is not true even if you look at the link you gave me (I don't know how many times I need to say this). The function to be integrated is $$k\sigma 2\pi \frac{zR'}{\left(z^2+\left(R'\right)^2\right)^{3/2}}\,.$$  Take a hard look at this and tell me whether this function always decreases as $z$ increases.  Plot it, maybe!

Comment: I based my statement on the fact that if n>1 E(R,n*z) < E(R,z), regardless of the value of R. So every element of your integral/sum should be larger when z is takes a lower value.

Comment: I did not deny that, for a ***finite*** $R$, $E(R,z)$ is a strictly decreasing function of $z$.  HOWEVER, $\lim_{R\to\infty}\,E(R,z)$ is constant in $z$.  This post is about the infinite plane, isn't it?  You can't easily use Gauss's theorem to get the electric field in the case of finite plane.  You don't understand your own question to begin with.  See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elesht.html, which states clearly that the plane is ***infinite***.

Comment: And this nonsense comes up yet again: "So every element of your integral/sum should be larger when z is takes a lower value."  You don't even carefully look at your own link.

Comment: I think I interchanged the term "element" and the field itself, forgive me for that. I see its evident now that the field's rate of increase decays as R increases, and the configuration which contains the larger distance from the plane will reach the other since its rate of growth is faster (it will eventually reach the upscaled version of the original system). Its sad to realize how little error in interpreting results can cause major complications. I apologize for that, and I thank you all for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that at larger distances each element of the charged plane has less effect on the resultant field, however the closer you get to the plane, smaller is your component of the electric field that is perpendicular to the plane (and the components that are tangent to the plane cancel themselves).